# Unity trying to access destroyed object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate a prefab object (bullet) and if it gets destroyed while the yield return seconds, Unity throws an error at the line where I set the rigidbody velocity to zero. It doesn't care about object null checks wherever I put them. The script is attached to the Instantiated gameobject.

```
public IEnumerator GetOutState (GameObject target) {

        state = State.GetOut;
        if (state == State.GetOut && gameObject != null)  {
            rbMissile.velocity = -transform.up * speed;

            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);

            rbMissile.velocity = Vector2.zero;


            StartCoroutine(FlyState(target));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What game object is this script attached to? You are checking if the gameobject attached to the script is null with

```
if (state == State.GetOut && gameObject != null)  {
```

did you mean to put

```
if (state == State.GetOut && rbMissile != null)  {
```

Also if this does not solve the issue, your issue is likely that:

```
StartCoroutine(FlyState(target));
```

Something in the FlyState method is referencing the null game object

if

```
if (state == State.GetOut && rbMissile != null)  {
```

didn't fix it your missle is getting destroyed between when this method is called and the one second delay from:

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
```

Two possible fixes: change the IEnumerator to a void method and remove

```
 yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
```

or else add in another check after a second passes

```
if (rbMissle != null) {
rbMissile.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. If I turn off the next state transition it still gets an error at the velocity.zero line!

Comment: I edited my answe for some more things for you to try let me know how they work

Comment: Thank you! ading rb.Missile.velocity = vector2.zero and StartCoroutine(FlyState(target)); to the separate null check solved the problem!